# Regex problem for password strength check

Tags: regex

I'm making a password checker that requires at least one of `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `#?!@$%^&*+-_` each. I made a rule but it shows false-positive. I don't know what's wrong with my rule. Thanks,

```js
const re = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*+-_]).{8,}$/
re.test('Abcde0927')  // This should be false. Why true?
```

Comment: Please don't require special characters, require a minimum length, that's way stronger and people can better remember those, don't have to store them somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your one condition `(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*+-_])`. You have written `+-_` which essentially means any character from `+` to `_` in the ascii table, and NOT JUST to include these three `+-_` characters literally.

You should always be careful while placing hyphen `-` within square brackets and make sure hyphen is either first or last character in that character set else its meaning will change like it did here.

Just change your character set from `[#?!@$%^&*+-_]` to `[#?!@$%^&*+_-]` and it works as you intended.

```js
const re = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*+_-]).{8,}$/
console.log(re.test('Abcde0927')) // prints false
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed by escaping some characters

```js
re = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#\?!@\$%\^&\*\+\-_]).{8,}$/
```

Comment: Escaping isn't really needed... just placing hyphen as last character is all that is needed. Also most special characters don't need escaping if they are contained within square brackets.